# Retrofit POST with jsonObject not uploading

Tags: php, android, kotlin, retrofit

I've been working on this for hours now and am not making any progress. I am new to retrofit and basically just trying to make a simple post request with jsonObject but  receiving this error:

```
java.lang.illegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 
1 column 1 path $
```

I've tried changing just about every bit of this code from the client to using multipart or requestBody and even my php code but nothing works, also tried echoing the inputs in script but it prints empty. Any and every response is much appreciated, thanks.

**Interface**

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST(BuildConfig.URL_REGISTER)
    fun signUpUser(@Body jsonObject: JSONObject): Call<Response>
}
```

**Response**

```
data class Response(@SerializedName("success") val success: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("message") val message: String,
    @SerializedName("userId") val userId:String)
```

**Client**

```
class ApiClient {

private external fun register(): String

companion object {
    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    init {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
    }
}

private val okhttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

private val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create()

val instance: ApiInterface by lazy {
    val  retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(register())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(okhttpClient)
        .build()
    retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
}
```

**Request**

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("username", username)
    jsonObject.put("password", password)
    jsonObject.put("email", email)
    jsonObject.put("termsOfService", termsOfService)
    jsonObject.put("profilePicPath", imagePath)

ApiClient().instance.signUpUser(jsonObject).enqueue(object: Callback<com.passionit.picnbuy.models.Response>{
    override fun onFailure(
        call: Call<com.passionit.picnbuy.models.Response>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@LoginOrSignUpActivity, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<com.passionit.picnbuy.models.Response>, response: Response<com.passionit.picnbuy.models.Response>) {
        Toast.makeText(this@LoginOrSignUpActivity, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        if (response.body()!!.success) { //success, now uploading pfp
            //successful response doing stuff...
        } else { 
            //error caught in script file
        }
    }

})
```

**Php file**

```
<?php
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Failed to connect: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$username = $input["username"];
$password = $input["password"];
$email = $input["email"];
$termsOfService = $input["termsOfService"];
$profilePicPath = $input["profilePicPath"];

//converting data
$termsOfService = $termsOfService ? 'true' : 'false';

//Username check
$usernameCheckQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM allUsers WHERE username = ?");
$usernameCheckQuery->bind_param("s", $username);
$usernameCheckQuery->execute(); 

if ($usernameCheckQuery->num_rows > 0) {//username exists
    $usernameCheckQuery->close();

    print(json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => "username already exists")));

} else {
    $usernameCheckQuery->close();

    password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO allUsers(username, password, email, tOS, pfPPath) 
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $query->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $email, $termsOfService, $profilePicPath);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();
    print(json_encode(array('success' => true)));
}

$conn->close();
json_last_error();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that sending anything besides an array or field added extra characters when received in php for whatever reason, I ended up just going with fields like so.

```
interface ApiInterface {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(BuildConfig.URL_REGISTER)
fun signUpUser(@Field("username") username: String,
               @Field("password") password: String,
               @Field("email") email: String,
               @Field("termsOfService") termsOfService: Boolean,
               @Field("profilePicPath") profilePicPath: String): Call<Response>
```

}

and in php its received like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$termsOfService = $_POST['termsOfService'];
$profilePicPath = $_POST['profilePicPath'];
```

Answer (score 0):

dear friend.
I suggest adding the following two lines to the build.gradle file.

```
    // Logging Interceptor
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2"
    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.4.0'
```

And use it as shown below

```
object ApiServiceContainer {
    private var apiService: ApiService? = null
    fun getApiService(): ApiService {
        if (apiService == null) {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            httpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
                val original = chain.request()
                val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                val request = requestBuilder.build()
                chain.proceed(request)
            }
            httpClient.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            httpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
            val okHttpClient = httpClient.build()
            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(EndPoints.API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
                )
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
            apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
        return apiService!!
    }
```

So you can see the errors issued by the server.

Comment: Thanks i didnt know this, I ended up finding another solution.